# Laravel duplicate package name

Tags: php, laravel

I have two laravel packages, each one with its respective ServiceProvier (both registered in the config/app.php) and each one is loading own translations (and views etc.) via the same package name. E.g.: the method @loadTranslationsFrom is the same in both provideres.

```
$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../lang/', 'packageName');
```

Do I understand it correctly that the ServiceProvider registered later would overwrite all the files described by the previous provider that were loaded under the same package name? And also, that it is generally bad practice to be having two packages with the same name? I'm just not very sure as to how does Laravel (^5) handle this situation.

Comment: The full namespace should separate the two, but you will have problems if they attempt to use the same aliases in the app container.

Comment: the thing is, for example the translation files do not have its full namespaces. I imagine the service provider to just say these files would be accessible under 'packageName' (i.e. trans('packageName::title')) but when the other service provider registeres itself it says "now, these files would be accessible under 'packageName'" thus the forementioned reference is therefore lost, no?

Comment: The translation files are in their respective package directory, so the loading should happen ok. The path hint however, I do think would result in a collision.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter the path hinting does definitely result in a collision (or at least it definitely seems like it does). Does it though mean that having two or more packages with the same hint name IS a bad and kinda weird idea? I think so but sadly I'm the only one in the office..

Comment: Yes I'd agree with you that it's a bad idea. 2 packages, 2 names, 0 conflicts.